# Error with pygame while downloading gym[toy_text]

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a Q-learning algorithm on Frozen Lake environment of gym. When I want to reset the environment, it's said that i need to download gym[toy_text]. When I run pip install gym[toy_text], it downloads pygame 2.1.0 but I have an error that I don't understand while 'preparing metadata'.

```
pip install gym[toy_text]
Requirement already satisfied: gym[toy_text] in c:\users\darkian\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (0.26.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.18.0 in c:\users\darkian\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from gym[toy_text]) (1.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle>=1.2.0 in c:\users\darkian\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from gym[toy_text]) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: gym-notices>=0.0.4 in c:\users\darkian\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from gym[toy_text]) (0.0.8)
Collecting pygame==2.1.0 (from gym[toy_text])
  Using cached pygame-2.1.0.tar.gz (5.8 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [77 lines of output]


      WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
      Using WINDOWS configuration...

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\darkian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bhryef_3\pygame_243ddab4cefc40b08b484f49e504b24a\setup.py", line 388, in <module>
          buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
        File "C:\Users\darkian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bhryef_3\pygame_243ddab4cefc40b08b484f49e504b24a\buildconfig\config.py", line 234, in main
          deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\darkian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bhryef_3\pygame_243ddab4cefc40b08b484f49e504b24a\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 511, in main
          return setup_prebuilt_sdl2(prebuilt_dir)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\darkian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bhryef_3\pygame_243ddab4cefc40b08b484f49e504b24a\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 471, in setup_prebuilt_sdl2
          DEPS.configure()
        File "C:\Users\darkian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bhryef_3\pygame_243ddab4cefc40b08b484f49e504b24a\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 336, in configure
          from . import vstools
        File "C:\Users\darkian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bhryef_3\pygame_243ddab4cefc40b08b484f49e504b24a\buildconfig\vstools.py", line 11, in <module>
          compiler.initialize()
        File "C:\Users\darkian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 403, in initialize
          vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\darkian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 281, in query_vcvarsall
          raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I don't understand it, so nothing much I've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. From what I saw pygame 2.1.0 isn't compatible with python 3.11. Just had to switch to gymnasium (gym isn't used anymore), that uses a more recent version of pygame, compatible with python 3.11.